# How to Compare values in talend and get the difference ?

Tags: talend

How to calculate time difference in talend say for example there is variable on_off in database with 0 and 1 i need to find the difference between the time according to on_off condition for some calculation. 0 has 7:15:00 and 1 has 7:30:00 i need to get the difference as 15 minutes using talend.

Comment: Have you tried using TalendDate.diffDate() function in Talend ? You can access it in a tMap through the expression builder for example.

Comment: But i need to get the difference of the time with respect to the on_off parameter if on_off parameter changes from 0 to1 and vice versa .I need to find the difference.

Comment: Can you provide the sample database structure and explain more on this?

Comment: sample db cannot be enclosed will give you explanation 
say for example there are two columns in table on_off and real_time_clock which is in date format of yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss  i need to find the difference in time when the on_off value changes from 1 to 0